# In Access VBA, Find field name, insert column into table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a new table where the field name in the source file is a variable. For example, the `ID` field in the source data could be "ID" or "HB_REF_NO", Date of birth may be `DoB`, `Date of Birth` or `Date_of_birth`

I've made a code that searches for various field names and returns the column they are in but am struggling to transfer the data from those columns into a table

Here is the code, please excuse its no doubt brutish methodology...

```vb
Private Sub cmdCompare_Click()

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set RecordSet1 = db.OpenRecordset("OriginalData")
Dim Fld As DAO.Field
Dim FldArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim SQLCreate As String
Dim SQLInsert As String
Dim s As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim p As Integer

j = RecordSet1.Fields.Count - 1
ReDim FldArray(j)

'Assigns field names to the array
For Each Fld In RecordSet1.Fields
    FldArray(i) = Fld.Name
    i = i + 1
Next

For i = 0 To j
    If FldArray(i) = "Surname" Then
        s = i
    Else
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To j
    If FldArray(i) = "HB_REF_NO" Then
        d = i
    Else
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To j
    If FldArray(i) = "NC_DATE_OF_BIRTH" Then
        b = i
    Else
    End If
Next

For i = 0 To j
    If FldArray(i) = "POSTCODE" Then
        p = i
    End If
Next


SQLCreate = "CREATE TABLE OriginalComp" & _
        "(ID varchar(255), Surname varchar(255), DoB varchar(255), Postcode varchar(255))"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLCreate

SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO OriginalComp (ID, Surname, DoB, Postcode) " & _
      "VALUES ('" & FldArray(d) & "','" & FldArray(s) & "','" & FldArray(b) & "','" & FldArray(p) & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLInsert

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this query show you the data you want to insert into `OriginalComp`? -> `SELECT HB_REF_NO AS ID, Surname, NC_DATE_OF_BIRTH AS DoB, POSTCODE FROM OriginalData`

Comment: I don't know how to check. The reason behind my doing it the way I have is because the files will often have different field names, so once I've got this sorted, I will need to change it so that it searches for both "Date of Birth" and "DoB", for example

Comment: Create a new query in Access query designer.  Switch it to SQL View.  Paste in the `SELECT` statement and run the query.

Comment: HansUp, that works very well

Comment: In that case, convert it to an "append query": `INSERT INTO OriginalComp (ID, Surname, DoB, Postcode) SELECT HB_REF_NO, Surname, NC_DATE_OF_BIRTH, POSTCODE FROM OriginalData`

Comment: Then if you execute that append query, assuming it runs without error, do you need anything more?

Comment: That looks like it would work but would i be able to use variables in place of the items in the Select part?

Something like this...
`Select ('" & FldArray(d) & "','" & FldArray(s) & "','" & FldArray(b) & "','" & FldArray(p) & "');`

Comment: Aha!  I notice you edited your first comment after I read it.  But that is not a deal-killer.  You can alter the `OriginalData` field names in the `INSERT` statement as needed.  Revise the question to show us the field name variability you must cope with.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, hitting return without holding shift.

The differences should be minimal, I expect something like this: 
DoB, Date_of_birth, Date of birth
HB_REF_NO, ID

Thanks for the help btw, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler to examine the source table's `TableDef.Fields` collection and find the current names for each of your variable field names.  You don't need to open the table as a `Recordset` and you don't need to use an array.

This example will find and use a birth date field whose name matches either `*Dob*` or `*Date*Birth*`.  (If more than one field in the table could match those patterns, you'll need to substitute patterns which are more selective.)

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strDateOfBirth As String
Dim strInsert As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("OriginalData")
For Each fld In tdf.Fields
    With fld
        If .Name Like "*DoB*" Or .Name Like "*Date*birth*" Then
            strDateOfBirth = .Name
        End If
    End With
Next

If Len(strDateOfBirth) > 0 Then
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO OriginalComp (ID, Surname, DoB, Postcode) " & _
        "SELECT HB_REF_NO, Surname, [" & strDateOfBirth & "], POSTCODE " & _
        "FROM OriginalData;"
    Debug.Print strInsert '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
    db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
Else
    MsgBox "Birth date field not found!"
End If
```

Extend that example to deal with the `HB_REF_NO` vs. `ID` field.

Comment: Thanks for this. I pasted that in and checked it, looks great. It returned runtime error 3192, Could not find output table original comp. I added the Create Table section from my code and it solved it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that, but I assumed you would not need to execute `CREATE TABLE OriginalComp` every time, and that you could just `DELETE FROM OriginalComp` instead.  But you can create the table as in your original version if needed ... or use a "make table" query like `SELECT HB_REF_NO AS ID, Surname, NC_DATE_OF_BIRTH AS DoB, POSTCODE INTO OriginalComp FROM OriginalData` ... the `SELECT ... INTO` statement would create the table with the desired data  in just one step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO OriginalComp (ID, Surname, DoB, Postcode) " & _
      "VALUES ('" & FldArray(d) & "','" & FldArray(s) & "','" & FldArray(b) & "','" & FldArray(p) & "');"
```

The `FldArray` variable is a list of all of the column names, so the `dth` entry will be the `dth` column name, which is why you are inserting column names instead of values!

If you want to insert into OriginalComp those values then why not do:

```
Private Sub cmdCompare_Click()

Set db = CurrentDb()

SQLCreate = "CREATE TABLE OriginalComp" & _
            "(ID varchar(255), Surname varchar(255), DoB varchar(255), Postcode varchar(255))"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLCreate

SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO OriginalComp (ID, Surname, DoB, Postcode) " & _
            "SELECT HB_REF_NO, Surname, NC_DATE_OF_BIRTH, POSTCODE " & _
            "FROM OriginalData"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLInsert

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been describing to HansUp my exact needs and he's been very helpful so I think I'm sorted but I appreciate your time.